# Removing white space at the beginning of values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, strip

---

I found a solution to this:

df['Name']=df['Name'].str.lstrip
df['Parent']=df['Name'].str.lstrip

---

I have this DataFrame df (there is a white space at the left of "A" and "C" in the second row (which doesn't show well here). I would like to remove that space.

Mark    Name    Parent  age

10  A   C   1

12   A   C  2

13  B   D   3

I tried

df['Name'].str.lstrip()

df['Parent'].str.lstrip()

then tried

df.to_excel('test.xlsx')

but the result in excel didn't remove the white spaces

I then tried defining another variable

x=df['Name'].str.lstrip

x.to_excel('test.xlsx')

that worked fine in Excel, but this is a new dataFrame, and only had the x column

I then tried repeating the same for 'Parent', and to play around with joining multiple dataframes to the original dataframe, but I still couldnt' get it to work, and that seems too convoluted anyway

Finally, even if my first attempt had worked, I would like to be able to replace the white spaces in one go, without having to do a separate call for each column name

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

> > > df['Name'].replace(" ", "")

this would delete all whitespaces though.